# Text together with subquery output

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a WHERE on a text+ subquery output but I get an error.
Here is my query

```
UPDATE labels SET text='bla' WHERE indicator='c_'(SELECT label FROM pages WHERE id='1')
```

`'c_'` is the standart text before the label, after it needs to be `indicator='c_home'` for example.

I tried to get the subquery also within the ' but that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like that

```
UPDATE labels 
SET text='bla' 
WHERE indicator = 
    CONCAT('c_', 
        (SELECT label FROM pages WHERE id='1')
    )
```

and you can read manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)